# How to use Vimeo APIs in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have an assignment where it says just two things:
We request you to create a simple page that consists of two elements:

- an input where users can enter a Vimeo video URL and a placeholder to
- load the video from the URL entered in that input using Vimeo APIs (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start).

I am super confused here as I have never ever heard or used Vimeo. And I have no clue of how to use a Vimeo API in order to just play a video with url. The simplest solution I can think of is use a iframe and use the url entered by user in the input box to play it on the page. But what about the use of **Vimeo API** in this case ? Can someone please help me with it? How to use the Vimeo API?

Comment: Have you looked into this link? -  https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics#connecting-to-a-vimeo-player

Comment: Also, this link may be helpful - https://github.com/vimeo/player.js. Just have to include like any javascript library. Example - jQuery.